# Sublime - put # at the start of a line rather the start of the code when comment

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

When inserting a comment into Python via <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> , it puts the `#` at the start of the code, like this:

[image]

I want to put the `#` at the start of a line, like this:

[image]

Are there any settings that allow me to do this?

Comment: A comment is not determined by your text editor. It is determined by the language. In Python, a `#` is used, while in JavaScript, `//` is used, etc.

Comment: @zachgates7 I just  want  to change the position of # , not change it to another character

Comment: @zachgates7 actually, you can...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a new file in Sublime with XML syntax, and the following contents:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Comments</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>source.python</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>shellVariables</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>TM_COMMENT_START</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string># </string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>TM_COMMENT_DISABLE_INDENT</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string>yes</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>uuid</key>
    <string>52CBA191-8A6C-4A04-8F2F-0D1642AE10F2</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

You will need to save this file in your `Packages` directory, which can be located on your machine by selecting **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`**. Once you've located it, go back to Sublime and save the file as `Packages/Python/Comments.tmPreferences`. For Sublime Text 2, the `Python` directory will already exist, but for ST3 you'll have to create it first.

The way the file works is quite straightforward. The `TM_COMMENT_START` value tells Sublime which characters to insert for a comment - a hash mark followed by a space in this instance. The `TM_COMMENT_DISABLE_INDENT` value indicates whether Sublime should insert the comment at the beginning of the line (`yes`), or just in front of the text (`no`, the default behavior). Please note that you may need to restart Sublime in order for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Thanks, but as I tested , there is no need to use TM_COMMENT_START here,since  the default comment mark for Python  is already # .

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @MattDMo's useful answer, you might also consider using a macro.  This may be beneficial if you wish to keep the default comment functionality, for example, but also want the ability to make comments in the manner you are describing.  Also, this general method of creating a macro and a key binding is extendable to many custom features you might want to employ.

Create it -  `Packages/User/some_filename.sublime-macro`

```
[
  {"command": "split_selection_into_lines"},
  {"command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "bol", "extend": false} },
  {"command": "clear_fields"},
  {"command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "bol", "extend": false} },
  {"command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "#"}},
  {"command": "single_selection"}
]
```

And call it by adding a key binding to your user's `.sublime-keymap` file:

```
{
    "keys": ["super+shift+/"], "command": "run_macro_file", 
            "args": {"file": "Packages/User/some_filename.sublime-macro"}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but when two lines of Python code selected , you method only commented the first line, also your method breaks the comment for other languages .